# Entity Framework - LINQ Expression Map many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, mapping

I want to find a single `User` and populate the `ICollection<Role>` for that user

I've got users

```
public class User {
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And the roles

```
public class Role {
   public string Id {get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Database looks like this

[image]

**I want to get a specific User by Id, all his Roles with a single SQL call.**

_context is my DbContext where we can queue User, Roles and UserRoles

With the following sql command I get what data I'm looking for

```
from users in _context.Users
where users.Id == id
join userRoles in _context.UserRoles on users.Id equals userRoles.UserId
join roles in _context.Roles on userRoles.RoleId equals roles.Id
select new
{
    UserID = users.Id,
    UserName = users.UserName,
    RoleID = roles.Id,
    RoleName = roles.Name
};
```

**My problem**

I want to map this result to the `User` class, it should create a single user and a `ICollection` of `Roles`

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Would it be possible using AutoMapper? How?

Thanks in advance!
Alex

PS: I do not want to use the stores offered by `Identity` since there is a lot of extra information to be loaded from the database and control the number of calls to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549270(v=vs.110).aspx) to group your result and use an appropriate projection for the Roles collection. Considering your initial query, you could  do the following (I am using the fluent syntax, you can convert it to query syntax):

```
var initialQuery = from users in _context.Users
            where users.Id == id
            join userRoles in _context.UserRoles on users.Id equals userRoles.UserId
            join roles in _context.Roles on userRoles.RoleId equals roles.Id
            select new
            {
                UserID = users.Id,
                UserName = users.UserName,
                RoleID = roles.Id,
                RoleName = roles.Name
            };

IEnumerable<User> result = initialQuery
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.UserID, x.UserName })
                .Select(x => new User
                {
                    Id = x.Key.UserID,
                    UserName = x.Key.UserName,
                    Roles = x.Select(a => new Role { Id = a.RoleID, Name = a.RoleName }).ToList() as ICollection<Role>
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication63
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Context _context = new Context() {
                UserRoles = new List<UserRole>() {
                    new UserRole() { RoleId = "1", UserId = "1"},
                    new UserRole() { RoleId = "2", UserId = "3"},
                    new UserRole() { RoleId = "3", UserId = "2"},
                    new UserRole() { RoleId = "4", UserId = "4"}
                    },
                Users = new List<User>() {
                    new User() { 
                        Id = "3", UserName = "ABC", Roles = new List<Role> {
                            new Role() { Id = "100", Name = "ABC"},
                            new Role() { Id = "101", Name = "DEF"},
                            new Role() { Id = "102", Name = "GHI"},
                            new Role() { Id = "103", Name = "JKL"},
                            new Role() { Id = "104", Name = "MNO"}
                        }
                    }
                },
                Roles = new List<Role>() {
                    new Role() { Name = "XYZ", Id = "2"}
                }
            };


            string id = "3";
            List<UserRole> results = (from users in _context.UserRoles
                where users.UserId == id
                join  user in  _context.Users  on users.UserId equals user.Id
                join role in _context.Roles on users.RoleId  equals role.Id
                select   new  { Roles = user.Roles, UserId = user.Id})
                .Select(x => x.Roles.Select(y => new UserRole() { RoleId = y.Id, UserId = x.UserId}).ToList()).FirstOrDefault();
        }


    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public List<Role> Roles{ get; set; }
        public List<UserRole> UserRoles{ get; set; }
    }
    public class UserRole
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
    }
    public class User {
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }


    public class Role {
       public string Id {get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
same result here though, the problem I figure is in the "select". since we get the correct result, all the roles for a user. in the example above, we get all "bob" roles, 1 role for row. We need to map each role for an entry in the Roles collection.

Comment: I made changes.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kBZeHk this is my current result. but it is getting closer. might be something like so.

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one role for the user?

Comment: https://ibb.co/bs5GV5 yes. as you can see there (from the dabase), I get all the roles for all the users. in the example above I'm getting all the roles for sure "bob". I'm getting the correct roles, the only problem is then mapping those roles to a List<Roles> on the server side

Comment: I will do some testing later to see if I can find issue.

Comment: I updated code to add test data.  Did not change query.  Works

Comment: was very close to what I needed. thanks for your time mate